# Binomial distribution probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A married couple decided to have $5$ children. Based on gene history, probability that any one of their children will need to wear eye glasses, independent of sex, is $60$%; probability that a child being a boy or a girl are equally $50$%. Let $X$ be the number of children that needs glasses and $Y$ be the number of boys in the family.

Probability distribution tables for $X$ and $Y$:

$$
\begin{array}{}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{X} & \text{P(X)}\\ 
\hline
\\0 & 0.01024
\\1 & 0.07680
\\2 & 0.23040
\\3 & 0.34560
\\4 & 0.25920
\\5 & 0.07776
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Y} & \text{P(Y)}\\ 
\hline
\\0 & 0.03125
\\1 & 0.15625
\\2 & 0.31250
\\3 & 0.31250
\\4 & 0.15625
\\5 & 0.03125
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

What is P(X=E(X))?

Let W be the number of girls that wear glasses. What is P(W=E(W))?

Comment: what do you calculate E(X) to be?

Comment: E(X) = 5 * 0.6 = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part: $X\sim B(5,0.6)$, so $E(X)=np=3$ and $P(X=3)=0.34560$
Since being a girl and requiring glasses are independent, $W\sim B(5,p)$ where $p=0.5\cdot 0.6=0.3$. Thus, $E(W)=1.5$, and $P(W=1.5)=0$ since $W$ is discrete.

Comment: If P[W=E(W)] = 0 because W is discrete, why isn't P[E=E(X)] = 0?

Comment: Because $3$ is an integer, but $1.5$ is not (I presume you mean $P(X=E(X))$).

Comment: What is the probability that the number of children that wear glasses is equal the expected number of children that will wear glasses (3)?
What is the probability that the number of girls that wear glasses is the expected number of girls that will wear glasses (1.5)?
So if the above is the question both would be 0?

Comment: The probability of $3$ children needing glasses is worked out above ($0.34560$). The other probability is $0$ because it is **impossible** to have one and a half girls that wear glasses.

Comment: @Daniel one might wear glasses and another a monocle